# using ifstream to read in number from a text file into a std::vector<int>

Tags: file, vector, ifstream

I have a read function which takes numbers from a text file and stored them into a data structure. I have made this function.

```
void VectorIntStorage::read(ifstream &in)
{
    if(in.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; in && i < n; ++ i) 
        {
            in >> vectorStorage<i>;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to add them into a vector structure, is this code correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. The canonical way would be:

```
vector <int> v;
int n;

while( f >> n ) {
    v.push_back( n );
}
```

where f is an ifstream.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you write you code this way the compilation will fail.
Maybe you can allocate enough space for the vector and then store the date the ifstream read.

```
vector<int> v(MAX_SIZE);
int iIndex = 0;

while((iIndex < v.size()) && (in >> v[iIndex]))
{
    ++iIndex;
}
```

Comment: This is so bad... Looks like C, that has been hit by a truck. Seriously. What was happening in the person's head while they were writing this?